# Cannot install speex using pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, speex

I'm trying to install speex-0.9.1 using pip. The error I'm getting is below. Any idea how i can work around this?

If I'm opening the tar ball which pip is downloading i can see that the .h files are missing.

Thank

[root@localhost speex-0.9.1]# python -m pip -V
pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

```
[root@localhost speex-0.9.1]# python -m pip install speex
Collecting speex
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/85/c4c50624de42a36965716369de69b7a5201b91331e91c3629a9301e5f156/speex-0.9.1.tar.gz (51kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 1.8MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: speex
  Building wheel for speex (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-q_1mmwjs/speex/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-s4ilcf7f --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'speex' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c speex.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/speex.o
  speex.c:347:10: fatal error: speex/speex_resampler.h: No such file or directory
   #include "speex/speex_resampler.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

[Speex](https://pypi.org/project/speex/) is a Python wrapper for [Speex library](https://github.com/xiph/speexdsp). There are no precompiled wheels at PyPI, there is only source code. To install it you need to [compile](https://github.com/xiph/speexdsp/blob/master/INSTALL) the speex library or [install](https://github.com/NuanceDev/pyspeex/issues/1#issuecomment-319564352) the speex library from your distribution.